# Mpu6050 and Adafruit Ultimate Gps not working together on Arduino Due

Tags: gps, adafruit, arduino-due, mpu6050

I have the codes for mpu6050 and adafruit ultimate gps breakout v3 and they are working fine seperately on arduino due but when i try to combine both the codes the gps does not get a fix. Can anybody help me out?
The code for mpu6050 is given below

```
    // MPU-6050 Short Example Sketch
    // By Arduino User JohnChi
    // August 17, 2014
    // Public Domain
#include<Wire.h>
extern TwoWire Wire1;
const int MPU_addr=0x68;  // I2C address of the MPU-6050
int16_t AcX,AcY,AcZ,Tmp,GyX,GyY,GyZ;
int minVal=265;
int maxVal=402;
double x;
double y;
double z;
double pitch,roll,delta_X,delta_Y,delta_Z;
double old_AcX=0;
double old_AcY=0;
double old_AcZ=0;
int led = 13;

void setup(){
  Wire1.begin();
  Wire1.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire1.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire1.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire1.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
 }
 void loop(){
  Wire1.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire1.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire1.endTransmission(false);
  Wire1.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);  // request a total of 14        registers
  AcX=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)    
  AcY=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  AcZ=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  Tmp=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  GyX=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  GyY=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  GyZ=Wire1.read()<<8|Wire1.read();  // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)
  Serial.print("AcX = "); Serial.print(AcX);
  Serial.print(" | AcY = "); Serial.print(AcY);
  Serial.print(" | AcZ = "); Serial.print(AcZ);
  Serial.print(" | Tmp = "); Serial.print(Tmp/340.00+36.53);     //equation for temperature in degrees C from datasheet
  Serial.print(" | GyX = "); Serial.print(GyX);
  Serial.print(" | GyY = "); Serial.print(GyY);
  Serial.print(" | GyZ = "); Serial.println(GyZ);



  delay(1000);
 }
```

And the code for the Adafruit ultimate Gps breakout is given below

```
#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>
#define mySerial Serial1
Adafruit_GPS GPS(&mySerial);
#define GPSECHO  true
   boolean usingInterrupt = false;
    void useInterrupt(boolean); // Func prototype keeps Arduino 0023  happy


    void setup()  
    {


      Serial.begin(9600);
      GPS.begin(9600);
      mySerial.begin(9600);
      GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCGGA);
      GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_1HZ);  
      GPS.sendCommand(PGCMD_ANTENNA);
     #ifdef __arm__
  usingInterrupt = false;  
#else
  useInterrupt(true);
  #endif

  delay(1000);

}

#ifdef __AVR__
SIGNAL(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
  char c = GPS.read();
#ifdef UDR0
  if (GPSECHO)
    if (c) UDR0 = c;  
    // writing direct to UDR0 is much much faster than Serial.print 
    // but only one character can be written at a time. 
#endif
}

void useInterrupt(boolean v) {
  if (v) {

    OCR0A = 0xAF;
    TIMSK0 |= _BV(OCIE0A);
    usingInterrupt = true;
  } else {
    // do not call the interrupt function COMPA anymore
    TIMSK0 &= ~_BV(OCIE0A);
    usingInterrupt = false;
  }
}
#endif //#ifdef__AVR__

uint32_t timer = millis();
void loop()                     
{

  if (! usingInterrupt) {
    char c = GPS.read();
  }

   // if a sentence is received, we can check the checksum, parse it...
   if (GPS.newNMEAreceived()) {
    // a tricky thing here is if we print the NMEA sentence, or data
    // we end up not listening and catching other sentences! 
    // so be very wary if using OUTPUT_ALLDATA and trytng to print out data
    //Serial.println(GPS.lastNMEA());   // this also sets the newNMEAreceived() flag to false

    if (!GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA()))   // this also sets the newNMEAreceived() flag to false
      return;  // we can fail to parse a sentence in which case we should just wait for another
  }

  // if millis() or timer wraps around, we'll just reset it
   if (timer > millis())  timer = millis();

  // approximately every 2 seconds or so, print out the current stats
  if (millis() - timer > 2000) { 
     timer = millis(); // reset the timer

    Serial.print("\nTime: ");
    Serial.print(GPS.hour, DEC); Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(GPS.minute, DEC); Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(GPS.seconds, DEC); Serial.print('.');
    Serial.println(GPS.milliseconds);
    Serial.print("Date: ");
    Serial.print(GPS.day, DEC); Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(GPS.month, DEC); Serial.print("/20");
    Serial.println(GPS.year, DEC);
    Serial.print("Fix: "); Serial.print((int)GPS.fix);
    Serial.print(" quality: "); Serial.println((int)GPS.fixquality); 
    if (GPS.fix) {
      //Serial.print("Location: ");
      Serial.print(convertDegMinToDecDeg(GPS.latitude)); 
      Serial.print(", "); 
      Serial.println(convertDegMinToDecDeg(GPS.longitude)); 

      //Serial.print("Speed (knots): "); Serial.println(GPS.speed);
      //Serial.print("Angle: "); Serial.println(GPS.angle);
      //Serial.print("Altitude: "); Serial.println(GPS.altitude);
      //Serial.print("Satellites: ");       Serial.println((int)GPS.satellites);
    }
  }
}
```

Both the codes are working fine separetely but i am unable to combine them and run in a single code.I tried to combine them and tha adafruit Ultimate gps breakout isn't working and it gives nothing. I want to know how i can combine them to work in a single code.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS) instead -- just add it to your IMU sketch:

```
#include <NMEAGPS.h>
NMEAGPS gps;
#define gpsPort Serial1

   ...

void setup(){
  Wire1.begin();
  Wire1.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire1.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire1.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire1.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);

  gpsPort.begin( 9600 );
}

void loop(){
  if (gps.available( gpsPort )) {
    gps_fix fix = gps.read();  // A new GPS update is ready, get all the pieces
    // Print some of the pieces?

    Serial.print( F("Location: ") );
    if (fix.valid.location) {
      Serial.print( fix.latitude(), 6 );
      Serial.print( ',' );
      Serial.print( fix.longitude(), 6 );
    }

    Serial.print( F(", Altitude: ") );
    if (fix.valid.altitude)
      Serial.print( fix.altitude() );

    Serial.println();

    //  Take an IMU sample too.
    Wire1.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
       ...
    Serial.print(" | GyZ = "); Serial.println(GyZ);
  }
}
```

This will display one GPS update and one IMU sample per second.

Also, you cannot use `delay`.  The Arduino will not do anything else during the delay, and it will lose GPS characters.  Notice that the above loop structure is always running, checking for GPS data.  When a GPS update is finally ready, it takes the IMU sample and prints all the results.

You also have to be careful about [printing too much](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/extras/doc/Troubleshooting.md#printing-too-much) information.  Eventually, the Arduino will spend all its time waiting to print characters.

NeoGPS is available from the Arduino IDE Library Manager, under the menu **Sketch -> Include Library -> Manage Libraries**.  NeoGPS is faster, smaller, more reliable and more accurate than all other GPS libraries, and the examples are properly structured.  It is very common for the **other** libraries' examples to break when they are modified.  Even if you don't use it, there is lots of information on the NeoGPS Installation and Troubleshooting pages.